# Cannot format USB drive to ext4

Tags: usb, ext4

i'm trying to format USB drive (some noname 32GB) to EXT4. It always hangs on step writing superblocks ... and always stops writing numbers after it reach to 125/256. I'm use command mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd1 . Command eventualy finishes, but drive is unmountable.

Do you think it is hardware broken or is there a way to fix it? I would like to use it with openELEC on rapberryPi.

I tried gparted live and gparted in ubuntu with same result. I'm going to try some USB drive check on windows, because it works as NTFS.

I have also tried gparted on different computers.

EDIT: i have now tried another flash drive (8GB kingston) and it worked without issue.

Is there some proven way to test flash drives?

EDIT:
ok, so i tried some test i found ...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16550256/cinska%20flashka.png guess that's it.

Comment: Try using gparted.

Comment: I tried gparted live and gparted in ubuntu with same result. I'm going to try some USB drive check on windows, because it works as NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

usb drives don't have advertised capacity.